# Proof of Hoeffding lemma

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

I am reading a proof about Hoeffding's lemma

> Let $Y$ be a random variable with $E[Y]=0$, taking values in the
> bounded interval $[a, b]$ and let $\psi_Y(t)  = \log E[e^{tY}]$. Then $\psi_Y''(t) \leq (b-a)^2/4$.

At some point of the proof it is stated:

> Now, let $P$ denote the distribution of $Y$ and let $P_t$ be the
> probability distribution with density
>
> $$x \to e^{-\psi_Y (t)}e^{tx}$$ with respect to P. Since, $P_t$ is
> concentrated on $[a, b]$, the variance of a random variable $Z$ with
> distribution $P_t$ is bounded by $(b-a)^2$/4. Hence, by an elementary
> computation,
>
> $$\psi_Y''(t) = e^{-\psi_Y(t)}E[Y^2e^{t Y}]-
>  e^{-2\psi_Y(t)}\left(E[Ye^{t Y}]\right)^2= {Var}(Z) \leq (b-a)^2/4.$$

Why $x \to e^{-\psi_Y (t)}e^{tx}$ is the density of the probability distribution $P_t$? Also, why $$\psi_Y''(t) = e^{-\psi_Y(t)}E[Y^2e^{t Y}]-e^{-2\psi_Y(t)}\left(E[Ye^{t Y}]\right)^2= {Var}(Z)$$ and the variable Z is used instead of $Y$? Could you please someone provide some details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why $x \to e^{-\psi_Y (t)}e^{tx}$ is the density of the probability distribution $P_t$?

They are constructing a new distribution $P_t$ but have defined it in a rather terse way so it is understandable you are confused. The given density is **with respect to $P$**, so if $Z \sim P_t$ we have
$$E[f(Z)] = \int_a^b f(y) e^{-\psi_Y(t)} e^{ty} \, dP(y) =  e^{-\psi_Y(t)} E[f(Y) e^{tY}] \tag{$*$}$$
for any measurable $f$.

This is known as an [exponential tilting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_tilting) of the distribution $P$ of $Y$.

> Also, why $$\psi_Y''(t) = e^{-\psi_Y(t)}E[Y^2e^{t Y}]-e^{-2\psi_Y(t)}\left(E[Ye^{t Y}]\right)^2= {Var}(Z)$$ and the variable Z is used instead of $Y$? Could you please someone provide some details?

I'll write $\psi$ in lieu of $\psi_Y$ for brevity.
Taking the derivatives of $\psi$ (and assuming you may push the derivative into the expectation), we have
$$\psi'(t) = \frac{d}{dt} (\log E[e^{tZ}])
= \frac{E[Ye^{tY}]}{E[e^{tY}]} = e^{-\psi(t)} E[Ye^{tY}]$$
and
\begin{align}
\psi'(t) &= \frac{d}{dt}(e^{-\psi(t)} E[Ye^{tY}])
\\
&= e^{-\psi(t)} E[Y^2 e^{tY}] - e^{-\psi(t)} \psi'(t) E[Ye^{tY}]
\\
&= e^{-\psi(t)} E[Y^2 e^{tY}] - e^{-2\psi(t)} (E[Ye^{tY}])^2.
\end{align}

Now consider a random variable $Z \sim P_t$ following the exponentially tilted distribution defined earlier. Applying the definition ($*$), we see that the variance of $Z$ is
$$\text{Var}(Z) = E[Z^2]-  (E[Z])^2
= e^{-\psi(t)} E[Y^2 e^{tY}] - e^{-2\psi(t)} (E[Y e^{tY}])^2.$$

Comment: @darkmoor I don't understand your expression at all. You haven't defined $\psi_Z$; the left-hand side has no $f$ but right-hand sides do; the expression does not depend on $Y$ at all. (I think you've mixed up $Y$ and $Z$ so it is really hard to understand what you mean.) Also, I don't see a discrete version in the Wikipedia page; please be more specific by what you mean.

Comment: In $*$ why do we have $E[f(Z)]$ instead of $E[Z]$? Also, why do we have $Z$ instead of $Y$?

Comment: @darkmoor They are using the distribution of $Y$ to define a new distribution; $Z$ is a random variable following the new distribution. The distribution is defined such that $E[Z] = e^{-\psi_Y(t)} E[Y e^{tY}]$ and $E[Z^2] = e^{-\psi_Y(t)} E[Y^2 e^{tY}]$, but more generally $E[f(Z)] = e^{-\psi_Y(t)} E[f(Y) e^{tY}]$ for any measurable function $f$.

Comment: A little better but there are parts that I do not understand. How using $(*)$ we show that $x \to e^{-\psi_Y (t)}e^{tx}$ is the density of the probability distribution $P_t$? What is the difference between $P$ and $P_t$? What is the meaning of $P(y)$? I am used to $dy$ met in pdf.

Comment: Also, the closest equation I could spot in wiki page that is close to $(*)$ is$$\mathbb{P}_\theta(X \in dx) = \frac{\mathbb{E}[e^{\theta X}\mathbb{I}[X \in dx]]}{M_X(\theta)}=e^{\theta x - \kappa(\theta)}\mathbb{P}(X\in dx)$$ but I do not see the immediate relation so as to understand how $(*)$ is derived. Could you please elaborate? I hope to get a response.

Comment: @darkmoor See [Riemann-Stieltjes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral). $P$ is the distribution of $Y$. The provided density is *with respect to $P$*. This is different from densities with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, which is usually denoted with $dy$ rather than $dP(y)$. If $Y$ has a density $g$, then $dP(y)$ is basically $g(y)\, dy$; however, the Riemann-Stieltjes integral can still be defined if $Y$ doesn't have a density. It might be more useful if you start another question if you have specific questions about understanding the notation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the comments!